# Can I control the unique key/ID that gets generated when I push an object to Firebase Array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am using the AngularFire `$add()` method, which under the hood calls `push()`, to add a child object to a parent.

[Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html) says that `push()` method:

> Generates a new child location using a unique key and returns a Firebase reference to it.

I wanted to have control over the Unique Key or ID that gets generated for the object I push. Like I wanted to prefix a constant to the random ID and then save it. Is it possible?

Comment: for now, it isn't possible as far as i know

Comment: can you use vanilla firebase here or are you restricted to using AngularFire's API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `push()` is a pure client-side operation. So you can:

```
var newRef = ref.push();
var newKey = newRef.key();
var realRef = ref.child("myPrefix_"+newKey);
realRef.set({ title: 'tadaaa', body: 'New child with a push ID and a custom prefix' });
```

Comment: With an overhead to delete `newRef` location, which is redundant after saving `realRef`. Good work around @Frank, thanks :)